# How do I make words align horizontally in a box?

Tags: tables, boxes

I have a problem with boxes. I'd like to make it so that a box including 2 words align horizontally. So the first word is above the second word, in turn hopefully making the box smaller.
This is what I have written so far:

```
\textbf{Elektriske komponenter}  & \textbf{Leverandør} & \textbf{Pris} & 
\textbf{Enhed} & \textbf{Antal} & \textbf{Sum i kr}
```

In which i'd like the ''Elektriske komponenter'' to be aligned, with ''Elektriske'' above ''komponenter'' in a box. I have created a table so far, but can't seem to find a solution, as to how to make words inside the box align like this.

Comment: Could you please (1) add a compilable example code not a description of your code and (2) a sketch of what your "boxes" would look like

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please indicate whether you use a `tabular` environment and, if so, which column types you employ for 6 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel} % is this correct?
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newlength\mylen % define a length "variable"

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
% Compute required width of 1st column:
\settowidth{\mylen}{\textbf{komponenter}} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\mylen} *{5}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Elektriske komponenter}  & \textbf{Leverandør} &
\textbf{Pris} & \textbf{Enhed} & 
\textbf{Antal} & \textbf{Sum i kr} \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why measuring? `\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Elektriske \\ komponenter\end{tabular}}` will do the same without needing to measure.

Comment: @egreg — Thanks. Let’s see if the OP sees fit to provide some much-needed additional information about the setup of the (outer) `tabular` environment and about what kind of text will show up at n the first column.